# How to build libvpx android aarch64

Tags: android, build, libvpx

I have built static library for android armv7. 
Now I'm need to build for aarch64, but cannot find documentation.

What I need pass to configure for build static aarch64 library?

Comment: What params did you use with configure for building armv7 version?